# Django Custom User Manager is not called when registering users on the admin panel

Tags: python, django

When a user is created on Django admin panel, `objects = CustomUserManager()` is not being executed. However, when I create a superuser from the CLI using `python manage.py createsuperuser`, `objects = CustomUserManager()` is executed.

Here is the model file

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("first name"), max_length=50)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the customUserManager

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, name,**extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email=email,
            name=name,
        )     
        user = self.model(email=email,name=name, stripe_customer_id=customer.id ,**extra_fields)


        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password,name,**extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
    """
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
    return self.create_user(email, password, name,**extra_fields)
```

Below is how I registered the admin panel.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    ....

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Below is the `CustomUserCreationForm`

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserAdmin` relies on the implementation in `ModelAdmin` to construct an instance, validate the form, and then save the instance, rather than calling a custom method on the model's manager.

Call chain: `ModelAdmin.add_view()` → ... → `self._changeform_view()`, which calls:

- (i) [`form.is_valid()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/561761c6606cd0e8bafb5e86c487871deb6e04e1/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1796) (of `ModelForm`) → ... → `self._post_clean()` → [`self.instance = construct_instance(...)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/667105877e6723c6985399803a364848891513cc/django/forms/models.py#L485),
- (ii) `self.save_form(...)` → `new_object = form.save(commit=False)` (of `BaseModelForm`) returning `self.instance`, and
- (iii) `self.save_model(..., new_object, ...)` → `obj.save()`.

You can override `ModelAdmin.save_form` to call the custom user manager's `create_user` method and replace `form.instance`:

```py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': (model.USERNAME_FIELD, 'name', 'password')}),
    ) + UserAdmin.fieldsets[2:]
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': (model.USERNAME_FIELD, 'name', 'password1', 'password2')}),
    )
    ordering = (model.USERNAME_FIELD,)

    def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        if not change:
            form.instance = self.model.objects.create_user(
                form.cleaned_data['email'],
                form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                form.cleaned_data['name'],
            )
        return super().save_form(request, form, change)
```

⚠️ Notice in the usual call chain that `save_form()` does not call `obj.save()`, as `ModelAdmin` handles multiple formsets and m2m models, while `CustomUserManager.create_user` does call `user.save()`. It is ok to change this behaviour in `UserAdmin` with known scope, though you may consider splitting `CustomUserManager.create_user` into `CustomUserManager.construct_instance` and `CustomUserManager.save_new_model` (move `stripe.Customer.create(...)` and `user.save()` here).

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, your custom methods `create_user` (and `create_superuser`, which you probably overwrote as well) are not called when you create a new user from the admin panel. I'm not sure neither to understand why but I think the `create_user` function is just a shortcut.

**Why not overriding the `save()` method of your `CustomUser`?** From the Django documentation:

> A classic use-case for overriding the built-in methods is if you want something to happen whenever you ***save*** an object.

Isn't exactly what you're looking for? Check the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) (to do so at the form level) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) (if you prefer change the model itself directly, no matter which form is used) for more information.

For instance, if you prefer the second option, you can add this method to `CustomUser`:

```py
from django.apps.apps import get_model
from django.db import transaction

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    # your initial code goes here ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # make the distinction between the creation and the update of the instance
        if not self._state.adding:
               # doesn't change the initial method if the user has already been saved in DB
               return super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # guarantee of atomicity
        with transaction.atomic():
                # dynamic resolution to avoid a circular import, might not be necessary
                customer = get_model("stripe", "Customer").create(
                    email=self.email,
                    name=self.name,
                )
                self.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
                super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                return self
```

Don't forget to make the distinction between the creation and the update of an instance.

Comment: When I do ´python manage createsuperuser.py´ then `CustomUserManager` is called but it is not called when I work on it from the adminpanel. So I am thinking how is possible to also trigger `CustomUserManager`.? Anyways,can you give an example of overriding the save() model which is also creates a superuser and user?

Comment: I've added a detailed example which hopefully will help you!